# Is this legal to publish SO contents on my website?

Tags: discussion, legal

I am willing to make my own website and there I would like to place special tips and those will be a collection from SO and other websites.

I wouldn't like to place that from where those articles, ideas came from in my all tips articles. But I would place the references just in my about page only like below:

```
References: 

http://stackoverflow.com/
http://css-tricks.com/
.....
.....
and from google searches.
```

Is this legal?

Comment: No, that's not nearly specific enough attribution.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Based on [the attribution required blog post by Jeff Atwood](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/) that is linked from at the bottom of every page across all network sites, you find this:

> So let me clarify what we mean by attribution. If you republish this content, we require that you:
>
> 1. Visually indicate that the content is from Stack Overflow or the Stack Exchange network in some way. It doesn’t have to be obnoxious; a discreet text blurb is fine.
> 2. Hyperlink directly to the original question on the source site (e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12345)
> 3. Show the author names for every question and answer
> 4. Hyperlink each author name directly back to their user profile page on the source site (e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/users/12345/username)
>
> By “directly”, I mean each hyperlink must point directly to our domain in standard HTML visible even with JavaScript disabled, and not use a tinyurl or any other form of obfuscation or redirection. Furthermore, the links must not be nofollowed.

I'm not a lawyer but in your proposal I don't see direct links to posts, nor to the profile page of users.

Based on that I would say  that your interpretation of attribution is too narrow.

Comment: @guest271314 I'm not sure what you're trying to tell me.